# Fill null values of a column with the values of the same row but different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and want to "copy" the values of column `findoc` and insert them in the rows of column `findocs` which have null values.

[image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` in a query:

```
select coalesce(finddocs, finddoc) sa finddocs, finddoc, sum
from t;
```

Or to change the values using `update`:

```
update t
    set finddocs = finddoc
    where finddocs is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) to take the first non-NULL value:

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename SET findocs = COALESCE(findocs, findoc);
```

Though a more efficient way would be to filter:

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename SET findocs = findoc 
  WHERE findocs IS NULL AND findoc IS NOT NULL;
```